# Reference for kernel integral regularisation

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Consider the integral operator
$$
I[u](x) = \int K(x,y)u(y)dy.
$$
The intuition is that, $I[u]$ will be more regular than $u$ in terms of the Sobolev space exponents, and we should get  some estimate of the form
$$
\|I[u]\|_{H^s} \lesssim \|u\|_{L^2}
$$

And we know the particular example of Laplacians, and many others.

The question is: where can I find more about general results that works for a generic function $K?$ Is there a **name** for this area of study (more specific than "harmonic analysis")? It would be very helpful if anyone can share some references.

Comment: You may want to look into the books/textbooks for pseudodifferential operators (perhaps also Calderon-Zygmund operators). You'll find plenty of old & new results of the form *if $K$ satisfies the property (...) then $I$ is continuous as an operator from the space $X$ into the space $Y$*. These spaces are often the smoothness spaces such as Hölder, Sobolev, Besov, Triebel-Lizorkin spaces.